# unable to connect to chat.facebook.com:5222 XMPP

Tags: php

I am making facebook chat api with xmpp. I have downloaded the code from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

But, I m getting error

```
Test platform connect for XMPP
access_token: <access_token_code>
server: chat.facebook.com
uid: 100002805874899
app id: 434781259869574
[INFO] Opening connection... 
Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to chat.facebook.com:5222 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ) in C:\domains\telecomlijn.nl\wwwroot\wordpress\fbchat.php on line 52
 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060)
An error ocurred
```

Below is my code

please help me out to fix the bug and run the app successfully...

Comment: If that's your code, the problem is that you haven't written any code. ;-)

Comment: I don't know if this `access_token` should be public, but anyway, you should remove it from the question.

Comment: I was able to connect just fine, can you confirm that there isn't a firewall blocking connections to chat.facebook.com or tcp port 5222 outgoing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that all sites on StackExchange network are public, meaning anything you place here would be shown to to world wide web. Please refrain from posting any passwords, credit card numbers, access tokens, database credentials, or any other personal information of you or anyone else.